# Regular expression for gettin data after - in sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with assignment numbers like - `11827,27266,91717,09818-2,726252-3,8716151-0,827272,18181`

Now i am selecting the records like

```
select assignment_number from table;
```

But now i want that the column detail is retreived in such a way that numbers are only retrieved without -2 -3 etc like

```
726252-3---> 726252  8716151-0-->8716151
```

I know i can use regex for this but i do not know how to use it

Comment: Never store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble. One value per row is the SQL way!

Comment: @jarlh , That is just an example of teh data.. my data is getting retrieved one value per roe only

Answer (score 3):

This will select everthing before the character `-`:

```
^([^-]+)
```

From `726252-3` will match `726252`

Answer (score 2):

You would use `regexp()` substr:

```
select regexp_substr(assignmentnumber, '[0-9]+')
```

This will return the first string of numbers encountered in the string.